# Building our own migration list

Tags: feature-request, support, moderation, migration, flagging

Now we've graduated from beta, wouldn't it be time for us to set our migration list?

I would propose:

- meta.security of-course
- superuser
- serverfault
- webapps
- math / theoretical.cs / stackoverflow

Does the moderators have some feedback on this in term of statistical of previous migrations?

[This query](http://data.stackexchange.com/it%20security/s/1047/post-migration-summary) seems to indicate that only 4 migrations took place. 2 SF, 1 SO and 1 SU.

Thoughts?

Comment: For 10k'ers... http://security.stackexchange.com/tools/posts/migrated/stats

Comment: What's the holdup? The suggestions from July were matched by stats posted from this week. Let's get it done. Can @RebeccaChernoff light a fire on this? (Sorry, I wanted to vote to migrate something today, and you're the staff member that chimed in).

Comment: We proposed this in July and selected a list then. We confirmed that list 3 weeks ago. I've spent the last two weeks nagging CHAOS / community team members. I've got another question to migrate, and still no list. What's the holdup, StackExchange?

Comment: until it does happen, you can always flag or ping us mods in Chat and we'll pitch in:-)

Answer (score 7):

Though I don't think we have enough outward migrations to provide evidence, in my opinion the list should be:

- Meta.Security
- StackOverflow
- ServerFault
- SuperUser
- Crypto

Answer (score 7):

Based on 90 day stats as of 3/5/2012, we should have as our top 5 migrate-to locations:

- 13: Server Fault
- 10: Superuser
- 4: Crypto
- 4: Unix & Linux
- 3: StackOverflow
- 3: Webmasters

I don't have an all-time list, but these numbers seem to fit with the sorts of things we have been seeing over the last year. Not a huge change since last month.

We should also have

- meta.Security

Comment: I wonder why U&L is coming in ahead of SO?

Comment: Good question - although I'm not sure the difference is statistically significant :-)