# Please provide Off-Topic alternative site options

Tags: feature-request, migration, flagging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Building our own migration list](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/422/building-our-own-migration-list)

Right now, you can only suggest moving off-topic questions to Meta. Can we get some options for moving questions to SuperUser, ServerFault, Cryptology? Also ServerFault, StackOverflow, Cryptology could options that transfer questions back to Security.

These related topics I think should be available for easier transfer without the need of Moderator Intervention.

Comment: Sadly, this has been an outstanding issue for months now.  Please see the linked duplicate question for more details.