# Can have our Migration list now?

Tags: feature-request, migration

Pursuant to [this question from a year ago](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/q/422/33), can we define a migration list for our site?

As of Aug.24,2012 - the migration stats for the past 90 days:

- Cryptography with 16 migrations
- ServerFault with 6 migrations
- SuperUser with 5 migrations
- Stack Overflow with 4 migrations.

This does not include Meta.Sec.se, a bunch of sites with a single export, and does not take into account rejections from the target site.

Comment: What would be good is if SEI can look at not only the past 90 days, but a longer term view just to confirm whether these top 4 are right.

Comment: @RoryAlsop absolutely. But that does seem to fit with our experience, more or less.

Comment: Totally agree with you, and looking at the point-in-time stats we had on the previous post this matches up, but always good to request data from someone with the overall picture as well (covering all bases)

Answer (score 1):

My suggested list is pretty much the same as yours:

- Cryptography
- ServerFault
- SuperUser
- StackOverflow
- <strike>Unix & Linux</strike> - removed, 4 slots only!

The reason I include U&L in there is that we do get a few questions that cover *nix stuff that isn't strictly security related. I can see a reasonably common occurrence of questions that would be better suited there.

However, if the Repurposing proposal idea takes off, I would replace U&L with that.

Comment: There are really only 4 migration slots available, because the 5 slots includes Meta. Besides, I dont think we have that many migrations to U&L, though there were a few - but by that same token, android / apple / ubuntu / etc... For those exceptional cases, you can still flag for a moderator.

Comment: Repurposing - you really think we would get a lot of those? So far there is only one - from today - that would be relevant there at all, but even that was NaRQ.

Comment: Ah, well if there's only 4 then I completely agree with your list! :)

Comment: Possibly. Then again, I think it's rare enough that we could just flag.

Comment: And the reporpoising one was Everett's test to check overlap with the Hacking proposal.