# Can we finally sort out our migration sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration

We had a [proposed list of migration sites](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/958/can-have-our-migration-list-now) a few months back, but nothing ever came of it. The community has matured enough now that we're having to do migrates daily, and it's (probably) becoming painful to manually migrate each one instead of having proper close votes.

Can we finally get this sorted?

Comment: Note:  This is at least the [fourth Meta post asking for a migrations list](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/search?q=[migration]+list) in our history.  The earliest dates back to [July 2011](http://meta.security.stackexchange.com/questions/422/building-our-own-migration-list).

Comment: Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?  Are we there yet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking at the stats, we enabled user-driven migrations to Super User and Stack Overflow.

Cryptography is unfortunately right out since it is still in beta and beta sites aren't eligible to be included in default migration paths.

We're also holding back on enabling user-driven migrations to Server Fault since they have a fairly specialized audience and the number of migrations currently going there from IT Security is quite small. We can review this later if that changes.

**10/29/2014:** since y'all haven't done too badly with the existing migration paths, SF is now enabled as well. Be judicious, and [respect everyone involved](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/).

Comment: Thanks a lot for getting this done, Anna!  Much appreciated!

Comment: The migration record from sec.SE to SF is actually pretty good: There are a couple of great questions, and only [one real groaner](http://serverfault.com/questions/465929) which is mostly because that guy's boss is an idiot. Keep flagging appropriate stuff to send over and if the quantity increases and the quality stays high I think this would be a sane migration path to open up.

Comment: @voretaq7: I think it certainly helps that we have users that are aware of, if not strictly "active", the goings on at [SF].

Answer (score 5):

Latest data from last 90 days:

- 15 Crypto
- 12 SU
- 9 SF
- 7 SO

then some others to UL, Ux and CS

Comment: I'd guess the SF rejects are just due to NaRQ / dupes. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Fun data point: We got ServerFault taken off the SO migration list when the reject rate was 50% and climbing.

Comment: @ScottPack So they're migration nazis? :P

Comment: @Polynomial: Nah, we were just fed up with years of being SO's dumping ground.

Comment: Had an excellent response from @Paulo over on Crypto - he went into all the migrations and then commented:

Comment: "the two closed question which make up the 13% in the last 90 days were under-specified, and the "How" one partly off-topic. Maybe in these cases it would be better to simply close and instruct the asker to ask again with more information on crypto.SE. But two questions in 90 days are not a big problem"

Comment: Does "percentage rejected" include those closed as duplicates? (I'm inclined to think it shouldn't. A question closed as a duplicate is still a good, on-topic question.)

Comment: @TRiG - I only know that answer for Crypto. See above :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is a request that has been ongoing for quite some time, approximately 18 months in fact. Without the magic of 10k rep to pull data from, it's hard to know what our migration statistics are like, however I believe it is time to get them added in.

Based on previous data, this seems reasonable to me.

- Server Fault
- SuperUser
- StackOverflow
- Pro Webmasters

I am purposely leaving Cryptography off since it is still in beta.

Comment: I'd switch Pro Webmasters out for Crypto - we have so many migrates over there that it'd be silly not to have it on the list.

Comment: @Polynomial: I would too, but StackExchange doesn't want beta sites on migration lists.

Comment: @ScottPack, do they forbid/prevent it?  I'm a pragmatic sort, so I'd say that saving time for our moderators might outweigh what StackExchange wants in this instance.  (I don't understand why SE would or should care, if it is on the migration list.)

Comment: @D.W.: Probably one of Atwood's senseless 'over my dead body' statements.

Comment: @ScottPack, right you are.  After some searching, here's a representative explanation on MSO: [Should questions that belong to Public Beta sites be moved there?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90061/160917)  Thank you for the explanation!  ... Personally, I would still recommend including Cryptography on the list.  In this case I believe the statistics Rory Alsop posted clearly justify it.

Comment: @D.W.: Oh, uncontested. That statement from the team is  the *only* reason it wasn't on my list.